# Tell one router to “get internet” through another router

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, dial-up

I have two router: one is a [Billion BiPAC 8800NL](https://www.billion.uk.com/product/vdsl/8800NL.htm) router and the other is a [Teltonika RUT950](https://teltonika.lt/product/rut950/). Currently the Billion is handling DSL dial-up and DHCP leases. Now, I would like to switch to that new Teltonika and let him do the dial-up but at the same time let my old Billion take care of DHCP.

Obviously I have to switch off DHCP for the Teltonika and give it a static IP, but how do I tell the Billion to "get internet" through the Teltonika?

Comment: Don't do this. It's totally unnecessary. What is your reason to want to do this?

Comment: My Billion assigns static IPs, e.g for Network printer and some network storage, so I do not want to reconfigure the Teltonika with all that info. Call me lazy but I thought it possible.

Comment: Question: Both have a WAN port?

Comment: Yep, both have WAN port, but the Teltonika is not using a modem to dial-up, but 3G.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

1. Ensure your routers are connected on the LAN interface in the same subnet and static LANIPs.
2. (As stated by you, turn off DHCP on the Teltonics)
3. **Get the Billion to assign the above assigned LAN IP address of the Telonica as the default gateway**

Comment: (From the link abive it looks like you cant connect a WAN port on the Billion to a LAN port on the Telonica because it does not have an ethernet WAN port.)

Comment: Are you sure? To me it looks like LAN port 4 can be configured as a WAN port.

Comment: Im not sure (I was jyst reading the link)  If that is indeed the case you could daisy chain routers and set up double NAT or extra routing but its probably a worse solution. (You would need to put the LAN interfaces un different subnets)

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound good. What about assigning the Teltonika a static IP and setting up IPoE on the Billion, using the that static IP both as WAN IP and WAN gateway?

Comment: You could possibly do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Get Router 1, the one that was connected to the internet, mac. Then clone that mac on the router 2, the new one. Connect a RJ-45 cable to slot 1(or the one you want) on router 1, then connect the other end to the Wan on router 2.

Change the local ip ranges on router one. Usually the ranges are identical between brands, `192.168.0.1` this will create a conflinct for ip solving. So you would want an ip range on one router like `192.168.100.1` and the other like `192.168.0.1` Thats' pretty much it.(The `.1` is just a example for this answer)

I set up something like this on my parents house, at the time there where no wifi extenders in their town but they had two other routers around. So I set them up to cover their whole house and it worked.

Cheers.

Comment: You said to clone the MAC but you didn't mention changing the old MAC on router 1. You can't have 2 devices with the same MAC address because you will get ARP conflicts. It will create bizarre problems that are hard to troubleshoot. The only reason you would do that is if the ISP made a relationship with the first MAC. The better alternative is to call the ISP after changing the router positions.

Comment: @HackSlash Well that's what ISPs do down here, never gave the thought it was different in other places.

Comment: I've seen ISPs do that. Like I said, just call them up after you swap the hardware. The tech will do something secret and it will begin working again. It's just NAC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Access_Control